# Difference between checking for cookie in PHP and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

I set a cookie in my PHP class, the page lets say foo.php, when triggered, loads data from database, by the ID that's passed to it i.e. foo.php?id=123 or foo.php?id=122.

Within the PHP using isset($_COOKIE['cookie']) this tells the difference from pages with different id's, even though the cookie shows up in resources->cookies on every page under this domain. I don't set a domain or directory when setting the cookie. Simple:

```
setcookie('cookie', 'cookie', time()+2678400);
```

However, using jquery.cookie if the cookies been set anywhere already it will show the cookie as true using:

```
$.cookie('flagged') === 'cookie'
```

How do I get jQuery to mimic the PHP behavior?

**Update**
OK, not sure why it worked at all in PHP, though have got the behavior working as I want it to now. I have set the cookie name as cookie+id and value as cookie, then checked if this cookie+id has cookie in it, makes much more sense anyway...